# Why is the "dialog" element disabled by default in Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, cross-browser, web-standards

According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/dialog), Chrome has supported `dialog` since 2014. It also says that Firefox does support it, but only if you enable `dom.dialog_element.enabled` in `about:config`.

The MDN page for the `dialog` element does not list any such notes, nor does it contain an explanation for why it's disabled: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

Why does Firefox have the `dialog` element disabled by default after 5 years of Chrome having it? Does Mozilla want to discourage its use for some reason?

Comment: There is not really a concise answer to your "why" question, but you can review some of the discussion about this issue at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=840640

Comment: That developer.mozilla.org page does mention the Firefox issue in the browser compatibility table, but you have to click the little down arrow under Firefox to make the note visible.

Answer (score 7):

There are some details on [the bug tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=840640).

In short, there are bugs with the current implementation and so it isn't considered ready for release. These are mostly accessibility related (for example, focusing the right element when the dialog is opened and closed).